# How to copy data from one node reference to another node reference in same content type

Tags: 7, entities

I have already saved a lot of data in a content type 'Events' in the node reference field `field_organization`. However, I need the data to be moved to the field `field_affiliation` also within the same content type.

Is there a way to do this with VBO and PHP command or another simpler way without code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) is rather not for this kind of job, I also don't know any other module to help you with this except the [migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module but I also think that it won't be of any help for you. What you are describing is called "migration", transferring and storing data from one place to an other, even if it is just one field or an entire website. Most migration tasks require at some point, if not at all points, code writing, code to  manage the data during the migration. Fortunately, to your case is just a field, so you'll need to write a small script by taking advantage of the Drupal's [node API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7.x), to transfer the data from one field to another, and that's it.

Rough idea on how to do it:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'events')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $nodes = entity_load('node', $nids);
}

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $value = $node->field_organization[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  $node->field_affiliation[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $value;
  field_attach_update('node' ,$node);
}
```

Use [drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush) to run your script by using this command :

`drush php-script site/all/scripts/script_name`
I know, this is too much for someone who has not much experience with Drupal yet but if you are really serious in getting involved with it you should start learning and use those things as much as possible.

Lastly, if you still insist to do it without writing a single line of code, do it manually, but you will soon discover that that way has a major disadvantage if your nodes are more than one or two hundred.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PHPMyAdmin or any other database viewing program, all you have to do is export the `field_data_organization` table and import it into `field_data_affiliation`.

Clear flush/cache in Drupal to see changes.

Comment: Don't forget to increase the `max_allowed_packet`  and `max_execution_time` otherwise the browser will hang in case of many items.